# How can I convert FetchXML Data-Source to SQL server Data Source?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml

I has created a SSRS report of CRM Dynamics using FetchXML, but now I want to create the report using SQL server, but I am stuck at converting Data-Source.

Any suggested solution?

Comment: quick question: Why do you want to change from Fetchxml to SQL?
w.r.t Dynamics Fetchxml based report is the supported way. SQL based reports are unsupported.

Comment: i need this requirement for some deployment purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used this couple of times. Try the [XrmToolBox FetchXML builder](https://www.xrmtoolbox.com/plugins/Cinteros.Xrm.FetchXmlBuilder/), choose `SQL Query` from the View menu. This will show the SQL equivalent of FetchXML.

[image]